Remotely controlling a computer without installing anything on it?
I need to remotely control a computer from my laptop, just like I could with RDP, except I cannot configure or install any software on the controlled host computer, meaning no RDP, VNC, VPNs or things like it. Both computers are on different networks. I won't have access to a desktop as my controlling client.
Here's what I thought:

This has to be partially a hardware solution, with hardware like a capture card to capture the video output and display it on the client controlling computer, then emulates mouse and keyboard USB outputs back to the controlled host computer.
From my limited knowledge about them, I don't think KVM over IP would work, because:

I believe these would the network to be very stable since it's not meant to go over the internet
I can't be lugging around a KVM/IP receiver, I'll only have a laptop.



This is a solution I've thought of, which would use a middle passthrough computer, but it's still missing what I'm looking for:
┌──────────────────────────┐  
│ Controlled host computer │  <- Can't install anything on it
│   (in network)           │  
└─────────────┬────────────┘  
              │ ▲             
              │ │             
            ??????? <- What I'm looking for
              │ │             
              ▼ │             
┌──────────────────────┐      
│ Passthrough computer │ <- In my control     
│   (in network)       │      
└──────────────────────┘      
              │ ▲             
              │ │             
      VNC/RDP over internet   
              │ │             
              ▼ │             
┌───────────────┴──────────┐
│ Controller client laptop │ <- In my control
│   (outside network)      │
└──────────────────────────┘

Maybe the passthrough computer is not necessary.
Does such a solution exist, and does it have a name?
Thanks in advance!
Edit (self-answered)
I was looking for the name of a category or a technology, if it existed, not specific product/service recommendations. Anyway, turns out I was wrong about KVM/IPs boxes: after some more digging, I found out some of them have on-board VNC server capabilities, which works for me and address both my listed concerns about regular KVM/IP boxes in the original question, without the need of a passthrough device. What I was looking for was: "IP KVM Switches with VNC".
Thanks to everyone who commented and posted answers.

??????? <- What I'm looking for what do you believe the arrows coming in and out of "what you are looking for" represent? ethernet? hdmi/usb? strings of magic cotton? I think if you combine the ??????? and passthrough computer in network you end up with a device commonly called an IP-KVM - but you don't want one of those

@JaromandaX I was thinking HDMI to read video output, and USB to simulate KVM input. Not that it matters since you're right about that second part: after some digging, it turns out IP-KVMs are the solution. Not the usual transmitter/receiver boxes I had in mind, but a transmitter box with VNC capabilities. Edited the original question to reflect that. Thanks!

Servers typically come with an optional out-of-band management module for such remote management like for example Dell iDRAC and HP ILO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management that allow you to access all the server controls over TCP/IP (power, BIOS, boot from install/rescue media, access console keyboard mouse etc etc) ; typically from a web browser
For existing servers/computers that don’t have such module : a KVM over IP (keyboard video mouse) switch provides similar if somewhat more cumbersome and limited remote management https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

There is a "less cumbersome" variant in a PCIe form factor, which can do more control over the computer than external IP KVM (it connects a front panel controls, for example). Or this one.
